# PHP Create a Zip archive for file only particular extension

Tags: php, zip

How to create Zip archive for file only particular extension in my case .TIF .JPG .TXT

Comment: Can you explain further what you are trying to achieve here? Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

currently i have added single extensions in code you can modify it later on.

```
<?php

/* creates a compressed zip file */

function create_zip($files = array(), $destination = '', $overwrite = false) {
    //if the zip file already exists and overwrite is false, return false
    if (file_exists($destination) && !$overwrite) {
        return false;
    }
    //vars
    $valid_files = array();
    //if files were passed in...
    if (is_array($files)) {
        //cycle through each file
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            //make sure the file exists
            if (file_exists($file)) {
                $valid_files[] = $file;
            }
        }
    }
    //if we have good files...
    if (count($valid_files)) {
        //create the archive
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        if ($zip->open($destination, $overwrite ? ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE : ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) !== true) {
            return false;
        }
        //add the files
        foreach ($valid_files as $file) {
            $zip->addFile($file, $file);
        }
        //debug
        //echo 'The zip archive contains ',$zip->numFiles,' files with a status of ',$zip->status;
        //close the zip -- done!
        $zip->close();

        //check to make sure the file exists
        return file_exists($destination);
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//your directory path where all files are stored
$dir = 'D:\xampp\htdocs\samples\zip';
$files1 = scandir($dir, 1);
// $ext = "png"; //whatever extensions which you want to be in zip. 
$ext = ['jpg','tif','TXT']; //whatever extensions which you want to be in zip. 

$finalArray = array();
foreach ($files1 as $key => $value) {
    $getExt = explode(".", $value);
    if ( in_array($getExt[1] , $ext) ) {
        $finalArray[$key] = $value;
    }
}
$result = create_zip($finalArray, 'my-archive' . time() . '.zip');

if ($result) {
    echo "Operation done.";
}
?>
```

i think this is what you want.
let me know if you have any issue.